# reducing json output while trying to retrieve only parent fields excluding child fields

Tags: java, json, spring-rest

I have this class hierarchy:

```
@Data // Lombok
public class CarInfo {
    private String brand;
    private String model;
}

public class CarFullInfo extends CarInfo {
    private Integer horsepower;
    private String engineType;
}
```

I need to develop REST API, where I can ask for a list of all cars, where is only CarInfo fields are returned, and there is another extended query, that returns list of CarFullInfo - extended, with 4 fields total.

I store all data in memory (I need to do it this way for some reason) as a collection of CarFullInfo objects, and I'm trying to figure out how can I reduce two extra fields if I'm not asked to return full info.

**First** my assumption was to find some JSON appropriate annotation to do this some way, but I failed.

**Another** try was just to cast subclass to superclass and return list of superclass objects from rest controller, but that also didn't work. I assume that happened cause THEY KNOW actual objects class and THEY SEE all it's fields.

```
@GetMapping("/cars")
    public ResponseEntity<List<? extends CarInfo>> getCars(...) {

 List<CarFullInfo> select = ...
 List<CarInfo> skimpy = select.stream().map(car -> (CarInfo)car).collect(Collectors.toList());

 return new ResponseEntity<>(skimpy, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Thus, my **last idea** was to create a new list of CarInfo and copy only it's fields - excluding CarFullInfo fields, but when number of fields grows - it gets cumbersome to do this:

```
CarFullInfo cfi = ...
CarInfo carInfo = new CarInfo(cfi.getBrand(), cfi.getModel(), cfi.getCountry(), cfi.getGeneration(), cfi.getModification() and more, and more)
```

I'm feeling there is some elegant way to do what I need. Direct me please.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**@JsonView** should help you. Take a look at the examples here - https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

Answer (score 0):

And you can use BeanUtils

```
@Service
```

public class CarService {

```
List<CarFullInfo> someCars = Collections.singletonList(new CarFullInfo("Opel", "Cadet", 75, "oil"));

public List<CarFullInfo> getFullCarInfo() {
    return someCars;
}

public List<CarInfo> getCarInfo() {
    return someCars
            .stream()
            .map(this::toCarInfo)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private CarInfo toCarInfo(CarFullInfo carFullInfo) {
    CarInfo carInfo = new CarInfo();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(carFullInfo, carInfo);
    return carInfo;
}
```

}